# Finding the rank of a matrix $A_{m \times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a H.W question which I try to tackle but unsuccessfully.

Given $m$ elements $a_1,a_2....a_m$ (not all elements equal $0$) and $n$ elements $b_1,b_2....,b_n$   (not all elements equal $0$) and a matrix which
defined $A_=m$ in order of $m\times n$ when $m=a_ib_i$ .

What is the rank of the matrix?

I thought to define the number of elements $a_i=0$ and $b_i=0$ 
, then I get a matrix which none of its elements equal zero.

The rank is defined to be the number of elements in the basis of the vector rows/elements.
In my head I see the example that $a_i=1$ and $b_i=1$, in this case the rank equal 1.
But otherwise, if $a_i$ and $b_i$ equal just random numbers, I don't see how I can calculate the rank of $A$.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advanc.

Comment: Dis you mean to say $m_{i,j}=a_ib_j$? Using the same index for $a$ and $b$ is not likely, as they have different lengths.

Comment: Yes. @MarcvanLeeuwen

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you meant to say your matrix is the $m\times n$ product of a column vector with entries $a_i$ and a row vector with entries, that means you have a composite of a linear map $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^1$ followed by one $\Bbb R^1\to\Bbb R^m$. Since you pass through a space of dimension$~1$, the rank of the product cannot exceed$~1$. (Another point of view is: the rank of a product cannot exceed the rank of either factor, and here both factors (the column and the row matrix) have rank$~1$).

If you prefer, you can also reason directly that all columns of your matrix are scalar multiples of the column with entries $a_i$, and therefore any two of them are linearly dependent. Any single nonzero column will prodide a basis for the space spanned by all columns.

Answer (score 0):

First we see $rank(A) > 0$ for otherwise $A = 0$.

Second, without loss of generality assume $b_1 \neq 0$. Then the first column of $A$ is non-zero. For $j > 1$, if $b_j \neq 0$, we have

$$ b_1 A_j - b_j A_1 = b_1 b_j v - b_j b_1 v = 0 $$

where $v^T = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_m)$ and $A_j = b_j v$ is the $j$-th column of $A$. Therefore $\{A_1, A_j\}$ is linearly dependent. If $b_j = 0$, then it is trivially true that $\{A_1, A_j\}$ is linearly dependent.

We conclude there is no other columns of $A$ are independent with the first one. Hence $rank(A) \leq 1$ and $rank(A) = 1$.